# How can I support direct P2P for mobile devices?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, mobile, godot

I'm Interested in two or more player co-op in Godot, via direct P2P without connection to a central server.

I have this idea that would utilize two smartphones in proximity to one another. I don't know an awful lot about Bluetooth or networking so please explain simply.

Comment: Searching "Godot Bluetooth" is turning up lots of promising hits. What have you tried based on your research into this so far?

Comment: @DMGregory I have looked, but was wondering if anyone else had already made some headway I can learn from. I will look more into it.

Comment: Yes: every search hit you get is someone who already made headway, from whom you can learn. So, please show us what you've learned by researching the work of those who have come before you.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry, I admit I had only just started looking seriously into this and had read just the documentation. I'll look into all that. Sorry.